# Can we make a "forgot password" link expire after XX minutes WITHOUT altering our database?

Tags: database, security, passwords

We have a security-conscious client, and in their "forgot password" flow, an email gets sent out with a link to reset the password. Right now, that link never expires, opening a potential security issue.

Our developer sounds convinced that the only secure way to do this is to add a field to the database and use that, but that implies pushing a whole new database to our client... not ideal.

What are the options for doing this, and are there any lighter-weight and less intrusive options?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'd need to save when each link expired somewhere.

Comment: How is the reset token stored now?

Comment: If there is a timestamp field for the creation of the record then that could be used as part of the criteria for reset.

Comment: You need to persist the timestamp somehow.  If you can't do it in the database, try creating an empty temp file with a name derived from the url.  Then start a background thread to delete files older than your time limit.  When someone clicks a link, check to see if the file exists.

Comment: @Orangepill why don't you post this as an answer? IMO that's the best way, but it should be somehow encoded

Answer (score 3):

When you create your reset token and send it to your user, you could create a secure client-side expiration date with a signature and attach it to the URL:

```
/reset/?token=foo&expires=date.signature
```

Or make it all part of the token:

```
/reset/token.date.signature
```

The signature is a function of a secret key and `date`. `date` would be validated by its signature, which prevents it from being tampered with. You don't even need to store the date in your database, as it can be extracted out of the URL.

I'm not sure what environment you're using, but there's a Python library that does this: http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a timestamp field for the creation of the record then that could be used as part of the criteria for reset. i.e.

```
// Pseudo code
if (($link_exists && $time - 3600 > strtotime($link_timestamp)){
    // allow reset password.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a field to your database is propably your best option, your developer is right there.

One alternative would be to include the date within the link and add a signature to it. Though it is difficult to make this safe, and it will make your URL very long:

- The date must stay extractable, that adds about 8 characters only for the date (it must be encoded for an url).
- It's difficult to build a safe signature, if the algorithm is known, an attacker can build his own valid links. Common hash algorithms will produce long strings, even a base62-encoded MD5 results in a 22 character string. So we have to calculate with a minimum of 10 additional characters to the link.
- A safe token should contain not less than 20 random characters.
- Because the token should be stored only hashed in a database, we have to include an id to the link, so we can find the hashed-token later on. This number can add yet another 6 characters.

The link-code alone will need a minimum of 44 characters then, together with the rest of the url this can become quite a long link. Some e-mail clients will have problems with long links.

I would recommend to spare those 18 characters and add a database field. Who knows, what information you should add as next, maybe a maximum number of clicks? The database is expandable, the link is not.